# Não esta gravando no banco de dados, sendo que as colunas tem números como nomes

Tags: php, mysql

Essa é uma parte do código que não esta gravando no banco de dados. Podem me ajudar?

```
 case 'questao':

   include "conect.php";
   $bd ="questoes";             
   $banco = mysqli_select_db($conexao,$bd) or (mysqli_error());

   $categoria=$_POST["categoria"];
   $enunciado=$_POST["enunciado"];
   $a=$_POST["1"];
   $b=$_POST["2"];
   $c=$_POST["3"];
   $d=$_POST["4"];
   $e=$_POST["5"];
   $resposta=$_POST["resposta"];

   mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO perguntas(1,2,3,4,5,categoria,enunciado,resposta)VALUES '$a','$b','$c','$categoria','$d','$e','$enunciado','$resposta' )");
   echo "Questoes inseridas com sucesso";

   break;
```

Comment: Aparece alguma mensagem de erro? se não mude o código para: `mysqli_query($conexao, ' insert .........') or die(mysqli_error($conexao));`

Comment: Aparece isso : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1,2,3,4,5,categoria,enunciado,resposta)VALUES ('Sustentabilidade','Biodiversidad' at line 1

Comment: Coloque os números entre aspas simples.

Comment: Tentei e aparece a mesma coisa

Comment: Me confundi, creio que é com crase...

Comment: PEssoal congeuir alternado os numeros para letras, parece que o msql nao aceita numero como identificador como coluna mas sim Começa com letraeo restante dos carecetres pode conter numero, só nã tenho certeza disso

Comment: E qual a finalidade desse break?

Comment: ah parte do código q estou implentando estrou usando o swtich;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NÃO é nada aconselhável usar números como identificadores sejam de tabelas ou colunas mas é possível sua utilização desde que os nomes sejam escapados com backticks (crase), isso serve também para caracteres especiais, acentuados e palavras reservadas como `DESC` por exemplo.

[Exemplo - sqfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f706/3)

```
CREATE  TABLE `10` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `1` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `2` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

insert correto:

```
insert into `10` (`1`, `2`) values ('a', 'b')
```

insert errado:

```
insert into 10 (1, 2) values ('a', 'b')
```