# Criação de tabelas com PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Caros;

Estou com um problema e preciso de uma ajudinha. Tenho uma página em html que contém alguns radio buttons. Ao clicar em um radio button e em seguida no botão enviar, redireciona para uma página em PHP que captura o valor do radio e com este valor, entra em um for, e dentro do for tem a função mktime, e com o valor do radio button vai acrescentando  os meses. Abaixo posto o código para melhor entendimento:

```
<?php

  // Dados da conexão com o banco de dados

define('SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DBNAME', 'contas');
define('USER', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', '');


$valor = $_POST['radios'];
$i = 1;

for ($i; $i <= $valor; $i++) {
$result = date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,date('m')+$i));

  $opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');
  $conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVER."; dbname=".DBNAME, USER, PASSWORD,                `$opcoes);`

  $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$result." (id int not null   auto_increment,nome_boleto          VARCHAR(70) not null,data_inclusao date not null,vencimento date not    null,valor_boleto VARCHAR(20) not null,mensal VARCHAR(4) not null,descricao    VARCHAR(50) not null,pago VARCHAR(4) not null,data_pagamento date not    null,forma_pagamento VARCHAR(13) not null)";
  $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
  $stm->execute();




}

?>
```

Porem não executa o código SQL, não cria as tabelas no banco contas. Se coloco um "echo" no final retornando a variável ($result), o retorno ocorre certinho.

Ps: Se eu coloco algum comando incorreto na variável $sql para forçar um erro, o mesmo não retorna nada, creio que este bloco não esteja sendo executado, esteja sendo ignorado.

---

Com a ajuda do rray, pedindo para printar o retorno do stm, cheguei em um erro de sintaxe:

```
Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax;    check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '2016-10-14 (id int not null auto_increment,nome_boleto VARCHAR(70) not null,data' at line 1 ) Dados inseridos2016-10-14
```

O MariaDB não está aceitando uma tabela com este formato 2016-10-14. Pelo que testei não aceita nome de tabela com formato data ou numeral.

Colocando a variável com "crase" escapando-a, conforme a orientação do rray , resolvi meu problema.

Grato pela ajuda pessoal!

(vivendo e aprendendo)

Comment: Qual a finalidade de criar tanta tabelas? a conexão com o banco de dados deve ficar antes do for já que não é preciso criar uma nova conexão a cada iteração. Talvez não crie pq as tabelas já estão criadas. Troque o `execute()` por: `if(!$stm->execute()){print_r($stm->errorInfo()));}`

Comment: o valor de $i começa em 1?

Comment: Geralmente em produção o usuário não tem permissão de criar tabelas diretamente (as vezes), eu optaria por criar uma tabela apenas e criar uma coluna com o valor de `$result = date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,date('m')+$i));`

Comment: Então, no html contém uma opção de criação de tabelas de acordo com os meses de sua escolha. Se o usuário clicar no radio button com valor de 12, vai criar 12 tabelas dos meses a partir da data que eles solicitou. Se ele clicar em 12 hoje, vai criar 12 tabelas a partir de outubro. O problema que não gera erro algum. Se eu coloco um código incompleto na variavel $SQL, deveria gerar um erro forçado, mais não. Simplesmente ignora. Por fim, sim o valor $i começa com um, porque o for acaba até o $i chegar no valor que o usuário selecionou no radio button.

Comment: Você esta criando uma tabela para cada dia? Acha isso realmente necessário?

Comment: Não, é por mês. Cada mês terá custos distintos. Na função mktime eu setei apenas o campo mês. É um sistema "pessoal" financeiro, onde cada mês alocarei meus custos e com isso gero gráficos e tenho um controle de tudo.

Comment: @user54154 sendo mês ou dia ainda sim não faz muito sentido separar em diferentes tabelas, é possivel distinguir com uma simples consulta na query.

Comment: @user54154 bastaria usar algo como `SELECT * FROM MINHA_TABELA WHERE data_inclusao BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2016-11-30';`, veja a resposta que adicionei.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme a resposta do [@rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/146413/3635) explica o problema do erro de sintaxe, todavia as vezes não é possível criar tabelas no banco dinamicamente, apenas manualmente (eu disse as vezes), isso tornaria a sua aplicação suscetível a falhas.

Outra situação é que notei que você já quer criar uma tabela para cada mês do ano, acha isso realmente necessário? Quero dizer você não precisa criar nada previamente, o melhor seria puxar realmente as únicas coisas que existem, vou explicar mais abaixo.

Se a ideia é criar tabelas para organizar algo por data então lhe recomendo usar a coluna `data_inclusao` da tabela criando uma tabela única algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE MINHA_TABELA
(
    id              INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    nome_boleto     VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    data_inclusao   DATE NOT NULL,
    vencimento      DATE NOT NULL,
    valor_boleto    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    mensal          VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    descricao       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    pago            VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    data_pagamento  DATE NOT NULL,
    forma_pagamento VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL
)
```

Então se for filtrar por data usaria apenas isto:

```
SELECT * FROM MINHA_TABELA WHERE data_inclusao = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
```

> troque YYYY-MM-DD pelos numeros como 1999-11-22

E se for o dia de hoje use `CURDATE`:

```
SELECT * FROM MINHA_TABELA WHERE data_inclusao = CURDATE();
```

Pois assim poderá criar consultas de query mais simples, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data_inclusao BETWEEN '2015-MM-DD' AND CURDATE()
```

Criar uma tabela para cada dia parece um pouco de exagero, se estiver tentando atingir algo como performance recomendo no máximo criar uma tabela por ano (talvez, tem muita variação).

Consulta por mês:

```
# Consulta mês 11 de 2016
SELECT * FROM MINHA_TABELA WHERE data_inclusao BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2016-11-30';

# Consulta mês 12 de 2016
SELECT * FROM MINHA_TABELA WHERE data_inclusao BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2016-12-31';
```

Comment: Olá Guilherme, de fato faz sentido e irei utilizar sua explicação para melhoria deste projeto. Grato pelo tempo que dispôs a me ajudar.